# How can I get only the mask of an image?

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I am trying to get a mask of a T-shirt.

Here is what I am getting:

[image]

However, I would like to only receive the garment's shape without the print in the middle. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image whose you want to create mask
img = cv2.imread('01430_00.jpg')

# convert to graky
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold input image as mask
mask = cv2.threshold(gray,220,220, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# negate mask
mask = 255 - mask

# apply morphology to remove isolated extraneous noise
# use borderconstant of black since foreground touches the edges
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# anti-alias the mask -- blur then stretch
# blur alpha channel
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0,0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType = 
cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# linear stretch so that 127.5 goes to 0, but 255 stays 255
mask = (2*(mask.astype(np.float32))-255.0).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)



# Show Image in Opencv Windows
cv2.imshow("Original", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)

# Save mask Image
cv2.imwrite("Mask2.jpg",mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You might want to check out Canny edge detection, after finding the largest contour

Answer (score 2):

You already have a large contour for "garment". You can fill inside of the largest contour with the following code

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,255,-1)
```